# AS3 Library Incompatibilities

Tags: actionscript-3, namespaces, swc, smartfoxserver

**Background:**

I am writing a flash game and have encountered a problem.
I have been using Polygonal's AS3 Data Structures (http://code.google.com/p/polygonal/wiki/DataStructures) without any issues.

I have recently added SmartFoxServer 2X support to the game (http://www.smartfoxserver.com/). As soon as I import the SmartFox SWC file, I get runtime errors on "new LinkedQueue()" calls indicating an incompatible override.

Anyway, I filed a bug with Polygonal and it turns out that SmartFox is using an old version of his data structures and have included it in their SWC file.

**My question:**

Considering that all I have is two SWC files, is there some way I can force on of them into a different namespace? this would allow me to use the new version alongside smartfox's old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if it's really important, and you want to spend the time, it's possible to modify the package in the swc by changing the swf and catalog inside.

Here's a sample AIR project using [SWFWire Decompiler](https://github.com/downloads/magicalhobo/SWFWire/SWFWireDecompiler-1.2.swc):

```
public class SWFWireCompiler extends Sprite
{
    public function SWCEditor()
    {
        stage.nativeWindow.activate();

        var bytes:ByteArray = getBytes('library.swf');

        var swfReader:SWFReader = new SWF10Reader();
        var readResult:SWFReadResult = swfReader.read(new SWFByteArray(bytes));
        readResult.swf.header.signature = SWFHeader.UNCOMPRESSED_SIGNATURE;

        for each(var tag:SWFTag in readResult.swf.tags)
        {
            var abcTag:DoABCTag = tag as DoABCTag;
            if(abcTag)
            {
                for each(var string:StringToken in abcTag.abcFile.cpool.strings)
                {
                    if(string.utf8 == 'de.polygonal.ds')
                    {
                        string.utf8 = 'de.polygonal.ds.old';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var swfWriter:SWFWriter = new SWF10Writer();
        var writeResult:SWFWriteResult = swfWriter.write(readResult.swf);

        writeBytes('C:\\output.swf', writeResult.bytes);
    }

    private function getBytes(file:String):ByteArray
    {
        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(file), FileMode.READ);
        stream.readBytes(bytes);
        stream.close();
        return bytes;
    }

    private function writeBytes(filename:String, bytes:ByteArray):void
    {
        var file:File = new File(filename);
        var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
        fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        fs.writeBytes(bytes);
        fs.close();
    }
}
```

You would then have to do a find/replace in catalog.xml, then repackage it.

Comment: I'll see what the guys at smartfox and polygonal come up with. for the moment i've got things working by loading the old version over the top.

Comment: Should I mark yours as the accepted answer? I mean in itself its not a solution but I don't expect anyone else to respond.

Comment: @Aaron I added some code in case you do, so now it should be an actual answer to your question.